# How to create Excel file in WP8?

Tags: c#, excel, windows-phone-8

I want to create an Excel file with C# for Windows Phone 8 Application, but I couldn't find a way.

I tried it with OpenXml. However, when I try to execute a code, I get this error:

> The type 'System.IO.Packaging.Package' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

This is the Code:

```
public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath)
    {
        // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
        // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.

        SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.MacroEnabledWorkbook);

        // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "mySheet" };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

        // Close the document.
        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Reference to "System.IO.Packaging" is missing. Add "WindowsBase" to your "References" and this will solve the problem.

Steps:

1. Right Click "References" on your project
2. Click "Add Reference..."
3. Go to "Assemblies"->"Framework". And select "WindowsBase"
4. Click "OK" to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the WinRT framework is a subset of the full .NET framework (like WP8 and Silverlight) but sometimes you get lucky and referencing a 'full' .NET assembly works.  If the WinRT .NET framework supported System.IO.Packaging, or if there is a version of System.IO.Packaging that has been ported over to the WinRT .NET framework, I should be able to reference and use the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll.  Even better would be a version of the Open XML SDK for the WinRT framework (hint, hint...).

This answer exists at:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/23c2154c-b6e2-4692-b4be-ca284fb74394/open-xml-sdk-winrt-windows-store?forum=oxmlsdk